# Need help in debugging SQL query

Tags: sql, database, join, sybase

I need help in debugging my sql query here.
Let say, I have table structure as shown below.

I want to merge result in one row having same Primary_Id and max(Row_Id)

For e.g:- For following

Table: custom_tab_instance
It contains only 'primary_id' and 'instance_id'(not imp here)

Table: custom_field_value

```
    +---------+-------------+----------+-------+
    | Row_Id  | Primary_Id  | Type     | Value |
    +=========+=============+==========+=======+
    | 4       | 1           | Name     | 123   |
    +---------+-------------+----------+-------+
    | 4       | 1           | Param_1  | 456   |
    +---------+-------------+----------+-------+
    | 5       | 1           | Name     | 456   |
    +---------+-------------+----------+-------+
    | 5       | 1           | Param_1  | 213   |
    +---------+-------------+----------+-------+
    | 3       | 2           | Name     | 745   |
    +---------+-------------+----------+-------+
    | 3       | 2           | Param_1  | 012   |
    +---------+-------------+----------+-------+
    | 4       | 2           | Name     | 203   |
    +---------+-------------+----------+-------+
```

Expected Result:

```
+---------+-------------+------+----------+
| Row_Id  | Primary_Id  | Name | Param_1  |
+=========+=============+======+==========+
| 5       | 1           | 456  | 213      |
+---------+-------------+------+----------+
| 4       | 2           | 203  | NUll     |
+---------+-------------+------+----------+
```

Current Result Set:

```
+---------+-------------+------+----------+
| Row_Id  | Primary_Id  | Name | Param_1  |
+=========+=============+======+==========+
| 5       | 1           | 456  | 213      |
+---------+-------------+------+----------+
```

I managed to get first row. But for Promary_Id = 2 , I don't see any result.

My query:

```
select
    max_cust.max_row_id as 'Row_Id',  
    cti.primary_id           as 'Primary Id',
    name.value         as 'Name',
    param_1.value      as 'Param_1'   
from  custom_tab_instance cti       
inner join (
             select max(row_id) as max_row_id, primary_id
             from custom_field_value where row_id !=null
             group by primary_id
        )max_cust
on max_cust.primary_id=cti.primary_id 

join custom_field_value name 
        on name.primary_id =max_cust.primary_id 
        and max_cust.max_row_id=name.row_id

join custom_field_value param_1
        on param_1.primary_id =max_cust.primary_id 
        and max_cust.max_row_id=param_1.row_id
```

What am I missing here? I tried to do left join but its not working.

Note: 
I am using Sybase

Thanks.

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Sybase? They are not the same thing. Also, I don't understand, given your sample data and query, how you're not getting duplicate rows in your result set. Each primary id has multiple rows that match the max row id. Your query should have produced 4 rows each for primary id 1 and 2. Either the sample data you have provided is not representative or your query that you posted is not the query you tried to run.

Comment: Plus, the query is the first time we're hearing about a second table. We know nothing about this table, there's no sample data, no DDL, not even a description of what it might contain. Since we know nothing about it, we know nothing about what happens when you join to it. Maybe that's why you don't see primary id 2, maybe it's not. We don't know. If that other table has a row for primary id 2, then I expect 4 rows in your result set for that primary id. Having said that, you are on the right track with an outer join. But you haven't shown us your outer join so there's not much we can diagnose.

Comment: @Rabbit I have edited question with more info. Also I have given you the exact information. I am not missing anything here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You debug this by simplifying the query and then adding a chunk of information at a time back in until you lose the record. Sort of like this:

```
select * 
from   custom_tab_instance cti       

select max(row_id) as max_row_id, primary_id
from custom_field_value 
where row_id !=null
group by primary_id

select * 
from  custom_tab_instance cti       
inner join (
    select max(row_id) as max_row_id, primary_id
    from custom_field_value where row_id !=null
    group by primary_id
)max_cust
on max_cust.primary_id=cti.primary_id 

select * 
from  custom_tab_instance cti       
inner join (
     select max(row_id) as max_row_id, primary_id
     from custom_field_value where row_id !=null
     group by primary_id
)max_cust
on max_cust.primary_id=cti.primary_id 
join custom_field_value name 
on name.primary_id =max_cust.primary_id 
and max_cust.max_row_id=name.row_id

select * 
from  custom_tab_instance cti       
inner join (
     select max(row_id) as max_row_id, primary_id
     from custom_field_value where row_id !=null
     group by primary_id
)max_cust
on max_cust.primary_id=cti.primary_id 
join custom_field_value name 
on name.primary_id =max_cust.primary_id 
and max_cust.max_row_id=name.row_id
 join custom_field_value param_1
on param_1.primary_id =max_cust.primary_id 
and max_cust.max_row_id=param_1.row_id
```

Note I used select * instead of your field list. This is because sometimes a different field is what is causing the problem, so it is often helpful to see all the fields when trying to figure out something relatively complex. Do not leave Select * in the final query. It is here for debugging only.

Also note that if you have a lot of results, you might want to add a where clause specifically limiting to the record(s) you are testing for such as

```
WHERE cti.primary_id = 2
```

Again that is just for debugging and you would remove it after you are done.

After you run each query above, check to see if the primary_id is still there. This will help you identify where it falls out and then look at the values in the previous query to see if you can identify which of them cause it to fall out when adding a join or where clause.

My guess is the derived table is the mostly likely place where there might be a problem. Or that data may not even be in the first table (wouldn't be the first time I got surprised by that).

Answer (score 1):

I'll start by adding a disclaimer that I don't have access to a Sybase instance so I've used MySQL to test this.

The query you've posted is *almost* correct however there are a couple of issues:

- You need to add an additional join condition for the two custom field values based on the `Type` name.
- Because you are currently performing an inner join this will exclude **Primary_Id = 2** from the results because it does not have a value for Param_1. As such you need to change these to left joins.

The following fiddle shows an example using MySql: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/dcb16/1

Comment: Thank you. Somehow I am not able to open above example that you have on fiddle